# Unknown response encoding: gathered by urequest.urlopen()

Tags: python, http, encoding, urllib

I am writing a web parser, which logins to the server(nothing illigal). The request recieves following response:

```
\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xabVJ\xceOIU\xb2\xaaV*K\xcc)\x052\x94\xcc\x95t\x94\xe2\xf3\x12sA\xec\x10\x7foW?\xa5Z\x1d\xa5\x94\xc4\x92D\x90\xa2\x82\xc4"\xa0LIjQ\xb1\x92U^iN\x8e\x8eRI~vj\x1eP\xa9\xae\x99\xb1\xa1\xa1\xa9\xb9\x85\x91\xa5\x89\x99\xb9\x81\x99\xb9\x99\x89\xa5)\xd0\xa4\xd2\xa2\x1c\x88J\xa0!\xb9\xa9\xc5\xc5\x89\xe9\xa90\x9dP.\xd4\xa4Z\x00\x94\x8a\xf6\xe1\x8a\x00\x00\x00
```

I've tried most online decoding tools, but nothing seems to work.

Here are response headers, if it helps anyone.

```
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Date: Sun, 16 Nov 2014 15:07:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 128
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: 0
Pragma: No-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

May be that Transfer-Encoding: chunked means something.

Any ideas how to decode that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your content is gzipped according to `Content-Encoding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is in JSON format and compressed with gzip. So to extract the data, try this:

```
>>> import json, gzip
>>> s = b"""\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xabVJ\xceOIU\xb2\xaaV*K\xcc)\x052\x94\xcc\x95t\x94\xe2\xf3\x12sA\xec\x10\x7foW?\xa5Z\x1d\xa5\x94\xc4\x92D\x90\xa2\x82\xc4"\xa0LIjQ\xb1\x92U^iN\x8e\x8eRI~vj\x1eP\xa9\xae\x99\xb1\xa1\xa1\xa9\xb9\x85\x91\xa5\x89\x99\xb9\x81\x99\xb9\x99\x89\xa5)\xd0\xa4\xd2\xa2\x1c\x88J\xa0!\xb9\xa9\xc5\xc5\x89\xe9\xa90\x9dP.\xd4\xa4Z\x00\x94\x8a\xf6\xe1\x8a\x00\x00\x00"""
>>> with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(s)) as gz:          
...     json.loads(gz.read().decode('utf-8'))
...                                                           
{u'messages': None, u'message': None, u'code': {u'value': u'7', u'_name': u'TOKEN'}, u'data': {u'url': None, u'token': u'-6311578294670676495', u'parameters': None}}
```

That should work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x. For Python 3 only, it's a bit simpler:

```
>>> json.loads(gzip.decompress(s).decode('utf-8'))
{'code': {'_name': 'TOKEN', 'value': '7'}, 'messages': None, 'message': None, 'data': {'url': None, 'token': '-6311578294670676495', 'parameters': None}}
```